# Searching a sorted list with two different algorithms to find if there exists an index i such that X[i]=i

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search, sortedlist

Note that the list will never contain duplicates.

The list is loaded from a text file and is the following `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.

My first choice since the list is sorted was a linear search and worked fine. Then I tried to use binary search but it does not work correctly.

Here is the code:

```
public boolean binarySearch() {

        int i=0;
        int size = list.size() - 1;

        while (i <= size) {

            int mid = (i + size) / 2;
            if (mid == list.get(mid)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (mid < list.get(mid)) {
                size = mid - 1;
            } else {
                i = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: to do a binary search u first need to ensure ur list is sorted. so is it?

Comment: What are you searching for?  I see no variable for the value you are trying to find.

Comment: I don't get why binary search could help you on this problem? you are looking for `x[i]=i`, how would you do the search?

Comment: I think you've missed the opportunity for an optimization. Consider searching a sorted list linearly for list[I]=I. Suppose we check the first element and see its value is 100. Do we need to check the next 98 indexes?

Comment: @z5h  duplicated elements?

Comment: what does "it doesn't work correctly" means ? maybe you could give us an input where it doesn't work. Even better, you print i, mid and size at the beginning of each loop and check whether you get the expected behaviour.

Comment: @kent, my comment was to the OP. I don't think binary search does anything useful here.

Comment: Then which algorithm you think it should be good for this case?

Comment: binary search gives you an answer in log(n) time. If the inputs are close to containing an index i such that x[i] = i or if you want to locate the position of the index it is still useful right ?

Comment: Can the list contain duplicates? If "yes" then binary search makes no sense. E.g. suppose you know the list is `[-1, ?, 3, ?, 8]`. There's no way of telling whether to look left of `3` or right, because `arr[1]` could be `1` but also `arr[3]` could be `3`. If duplicates are not allowed, binary search *does* make sense.

Comment: I want to find if this condition x[i]=i is true or false in my list

Comment: I know that. Can the list contain duplicates?

Comment: Yes no duplicates are allowed

Comment: @vib, binary search helps you find the index of a specific value. That's not at all what we are doing. It doesn't help us in any way.

Comment: So, binary search is not efficient in order to find if X[i]=i exists in a sorted list without duplicates?

Comment: @z5h It does. If the list can't contain duplicates (which the OP has confirmed), the numbers `x[i] - i` are increasing from left to right. We are searching for a value of `0` for `x[i] - i`.

Comment: So user3469716 could you answer my question ? Otherwise we are just all searching in the black here.

Comment: I've posted a solution that does not use binary search. Sorry its not proper Java. I'll clean it up when I get a chance.

Comment: I might point out that your algorithm works for the input {0, 1, 2, 3, 4...} as then you will have an i such that X[i] == i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an `O(log n)` solution.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(binarySearch(new int[] {-100, -50, -30, 3, 500, 800}));
    System.out.println(binarySearch(new int[] {-100, -50, -30, 42, 500, 800}));
    System.out.println(binarySearch(new int[] {-8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 200, 300, 500, 700, 9000}));
}

// Searches for a solution to x[i]=i, returning -1 if no solutions exist.
// The algorithm only works if the array is in ascending order and has no repeats.
// If there is more than one solution there is no guarantee which will
// be returned. Worst case time complexity O(log n) where n is length of array.
public static int binarySearch(int[] x) {
    if (x == null || x.length == 0)
        return -1;
    int low = 0;
    if (x[low] == low)
        return 0;
    else if (x[low] > low)
        return -1;
    int high = x.length - 1;
    if (x[high] == high)
        return high;
    else if (x[high] < high)
        return -1;
    while (high - low >= 2) {
        int mid = (high + low) / 2;
        if (x[mid] == mid)
            return mid;
        else if (x[mid] > mid)
            high = mid;
        else low = mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: So if the first element is 1, x[low] > low. and the rest of the array is not checked. It fails in constant time!

Comment: Correct. The elements are all different so the lowest the elements could possibly be is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....`. No `i` could possibly equal `x[i]`.

Comment: This is assuming that the first index is numbered 0.

Comment: Yes I am assuming that. If you want me to add in a `base` parameter for the index of the first number, I will do that.

Comment: find if there exists **an** index i such that X[i]=i. That's what we're looking for. Any single i in the whole array where X[i]=i.

Comment: @z5h I've done that. If there exists an index such that `x[i] == i` the method will not return `-1`. Can the downvoter please explain what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: This algorithm is working perfectly. Either you take the OP original exemple of an array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and then either all i satisfies x[i] =i or none of them (depending on your indexing convention). Or we try to generalize a bit and then we need to consider an array where x[i] can be either negative or larger than size-1. And then this algorithm works just fine. I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: Can we not have [1,1]?? The post says nothing about duplicates.

Comment: No. I asked the OP in the comments and he/she said no duplicates. That's why I asked. You can't do binary search if duplicates are allowed.

Comment: AAAAAHHHH. For F sake. That makes this completely different. Editing the original post...

Comment: Now that we're all agreed this answer is correct, can the downvoter please retract it?

Comment: I can't change my vote until your solution is modified. Make any tiny change.

Comment: I changed a number to `42`. I should have included `42` in the first place!

Comment: Its ok, now I get it! Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score -1):

public class NewMain1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] x = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int value = 7;
    boolean check = binarySearch(x,value);
    System.out.println(check);
}
public static boolean binarySearch(int [] list , int value) {

    int i=0;
    int size = list.length - 1;

    while (i <= size) {

        int mid = (i + size) / 2;
        if (value == list[mid]) {
            return true;
        }
        if (value < list[mid]) {
            size = mid - 1;
        } else {
            i = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I think this could help you

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to what you changed.

Comment: first the parameters are the list and the value that we want to search . int i =0; // this is as a counter to traverse the list. the idea of binary search is to divide the list in the half . so we should get the size then divide by 2 . forget now about "while" condition . now after we divide we store the value in "mid". then,use "mid" as index to compare "value" with list. this will keep going till "i" become greater than size . last suggestion try to trace my code on paper it will be more clear.